# Django - Finding all related OneToOneField objects through the foreign object

Tags: django, django-models, orm, one-to-one

Sorry if that title isn't clear, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ParentClass(models.Model)
    document = models.OneToOneField(Document, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def do_something():
        raise NotImplementedError()

class SubclassOne(ParentClass):
    # Some fields.
    def do_something(self):
        # Something specific to this subclass

class SubclassTwo(ParentClass):
    # Some other fields.
    def do_something(self):
        # Something specific to this subclass
```

My first thought was to try querying through the `ParentClass`

```
ParentClass.objects.filter(document__processed=False)
```

But that doesn't work because the parent class is `abstract`.

Now I have tried going through the `Document` object

```
Document.objects.filter(processed=False)
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to look up the related objects through each individual `Document`. I'm not sure that's a good solution anyways because of the tight coupling of the `ParentClass` to the `Document`, which shouldn't need to be aware of `ParentClass`'s implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all reverse related field names, and can loop over that as below:

```
documents = Document.objects.filter(processed=False)
reverse_related_fields = Document._meta.get_fields()

for document in documents:
    for reverse_related_field in reverse_related_fields:
        if reverse_related_field.one_to_one:
            attr = getattr(document, f"{reverse_related_field.name}_set")
            try:
                attr.get().do_something
            except Exception:
                pass
```

Comment: Yes, that will get me the results for instances of `SubclassOne `, but I need a way to get results that include `SubclassTwo` (and eventually `SubclassThree`, `SubclassFour`, etc).

Comment: Oh got it! Editing my answer. You can do it through reverse lookup.

Answer (score 0):

```py
ParentClass.objects.filter(document__processed=False)
```

This will return all Documents that have processed set to `False`.

Comment: I tried this (I should have included it in my example code), but I got an `AttributeError: type object 'ParentClass' has no attribute 'objects'` . I'm guessing that is because `ParentClass` is defined as `abstract`.

Comment: Oh you are right haven't noticed that. This solution could be only used if you remove the abstract class but I guess that does not help you, my bad